# Translate Resources

Tags: .net, resources

How Can i translate .Net resources to another language?
i am looking for a software that able me to translate .NET resource from a language to another language.
For example Persian to English.
i saw the software that used Google translate API for translating.
but it just translated from English to another...
thanks.
Please Introduce some tools for me.

Comment: I found an open source App for translating resources.
http://resxtranslator.codeplex.com/

Comment: Tools to do this might be okay, but you really should find/hire a native speaker for the translation otherwise you can end up with insane results. For example, have you ever heard of [Engrish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish) which is the sometimes hilarious literal translation of Chinese/Japanese into English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [ResEx](http://resex.codeplex.com/) for translating .resx-files. It allows you to view the (untranslated) source and the target language side-by-side. It also can use Microsoft Translator services for automated translation. That way you can have something to start with (although as is the case with all machine translations, you should have someone who knows the language well look at it).

Comment: @shaahin You have to translate the resources one string at a time. The software also has a percentage display of how much has been translated already.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) for translating .resx Files. It's free and has many usefull features. It enables you to edit the files outside of Visual Studio.